# SQL Server built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update sum columns data like this:

```
update
   tableName
set
   score = myFunction(tableName.id)
```

In other hands I want to have a table like this:

```
column1   |     column2
------------------------------    
  id1     |  myFunction(id1)
  id2     |  myFunction(id2) 
  id3     |  myFunction(id3)
  id4     |  myFunction(id4)
```

I defined `myFunction` as a scalar-valued functions. I also tried it as a table-valued function
but I see this error in SQL Server 2012:

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 14
>   'myFunction' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Please help me

Comment: So, where do you define myFunction? It tells you an obvious thing - myFunction is not a built-in function.

Comment: I defined myFunction is scalar-valued functions

Comment: Need to add the schema name before the function name, say dbo.myfunction()

Comment: Have you considered that `score` may be better as a computed column (and thus always correct) rather than having to run this `UPDATE` at appropriate times?

Comment: It worked by using schema name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the full name of the function, including the database and schema name:

```
update
   tableName
set
   score = <database>.<schema>.myFunction(tableName.id)
```

I think only the schema name is needed, but I've gotten in the habit of putting both.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175562%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) explains that at least the two part name is needed.  If you don't know what schema are, then the following will probably work:

```
update
   tableName
set
   score = dbo.myFunction(tableName.id)
```